# Add a value to the last column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How do you go about adding a value to the last column of a matrix.

For example if I have a 3x3 matrix where all the values are 1. How do i select and add 3 to the third column such that the last column has values of 3 instead of 1.

Regards,
Jerry

Comment: Do you know the [`colon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html?refresh=true) operator?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the accessor for matrix to get the vector you want to modify (i.e. last column vector) and create the vector you want to put in:

```
mat(:, 3) = [1; 2; 3];
```

And in your case you want to fill the vector with a single value, you can use:

```
mat(:, 3) = 3*ones(1, 3);
```

or

```
mat(:, 3) = 3;
```

Comment: I understand why you have used that but say if the matrix was as follows ``x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`` How would I add a value such a 3 to the last column of this matrix?

Comment: Exactly the same way, `mat(:,3)` is the third column of your matrix. And in my example, `3*ones(3,1)` is simply a more efficient way to write `[3;3;3]`.

Comment: `mat(:, 3) = 3` works too and is more readable. I suggest you change your answer...

Comment: @percusse why not? I think it is. MATLAB broadcasts scalars for a reason.

Comment: @Dan You will spend hours debugging such things. And matlab broadcasting is not fun at all.

Comment: @Dan, @percusse, I always use the `ones` function to generate single value filled matrix and I think it is clearer and less prone to error to attribute a matrix to another... But if matlab populate the matrix with the value, why not use the simpler solution... So to please everyone, all possibilities included in my answer.

Comment: @percusse Can you demonstrate a concrete example of when using the scalar would be more error prone. It lets me specify two fewer numbers (i.e. the dimensions) which looks like less room for error to me. I can't say I have ever had a problem doing it. Perhaps you can link to an article showing why it's bad practice.

Comment: @Dan `3+eye(2)` what would you expect from this from math point of view? (I'm asking the legibility part I know what it gives)

Comment: I expect `[4,3;3,4]`

Comment: Well it should give `4*eye(2)` if it was legible

Comment: @percusse why? That's your interpration. But there is no reason why that should be the case mathematically. As far as I know, to get what you want you'd write something like 3I + I which in matlab is `3*eye(2) + eye(2)`. 3 + I is not defined so MATLAB is free to define it as a broadcasting since it is very useful in many other areas.

Comment: @Dan Not quite. It's because you are used to it. In math a scalar is *broadcasted* to identity always. Unfortunately, this is just easier to program by the developers but pretty unintuitive for matrix people. Ones matrix is pretty uncommon in matrix related computations.

Comment: @percusse WolframAlpha disagrees with you (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B3,2%5D;%5B5,6%5D%5D+%2B+3)

Comment: @Dan Read the *unfortunately* part. I am one of those people

Comment: @percusse If you're going to create the correct sized vector, you should avoid magic numbers. Instead, you should use `value*(size(mat, 1), 1)`.